# zsh: redirect only standard error to /dev/null

Tags: zsh

I want to use something like `pdfs=$(echo *.pdf)` and drop the error message that comes in case of no files present. But the [docs](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Redirection.html) have only examples where both outputs are redirected combined.

Answer (score 5):

Standard error is file descriptor 2, if you are actually running a command you expect to produce output to standard error.

```
pdfs=$(echo *.pdf 2> /dev/null)
```

However, don't write code like in your example. A flat string cannot usefully store an arbitrary list of file names, because you can't distinguish between filename delimiters and valid characters in a filename. Instead, use an array which doesn't require any separate commands (and thus any need to redirect standard error):

```
pdfs=( *.pdf(N) )  # You can drop the (N) if you already have NULL_GLOB enabled
```

Comment: Sure it does, if `echo` is the command actually producing the error. As `echo` wasn't the right thing to use in the first place, I didn't address the issue. However, in the given solution, `*.pdf` itself can raise an error by default if no files match. *That* can be fixed with `pdfs=( *.pdf(N))` to set the `NULL_GLOB` option for this pattern. This pattern can expand to 0 files instead of causing an error.